# How to delete an app from a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Initially I made 2 apps (app_a and app_b) in a single project in Ruby. Now I want to delete one (say app_a). How should I do so? Is deleting the app folder sufficient?

Comment: how you distinguish term 'project' and 'app'

Comment: something like this should work `rm -rf app_a`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to drop your related database and then delete the app directory

```
# from app directory
rake db:drop
cd .. && rm -rf app_a
```

Rails generator command creates a copy of the framework. The app directory id self contained. Deleting it is enough. If you are using `sqlite` as your database then you can skip first command.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the app folder will get rid of it.  Be sure to clean up your routes file if needed as well as get rid of a database table if it was created.